# Dynamic variable names in php not working

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

Suppose i have the following variable

```
$a="stack";

$b="overflow";
```

now i want to create another variable using the variable `$a` and `$b` .I want the new variable to be `$stack_overflow ="The best place to learn programming";`

I tried the following to create the variable `$stack_overflow` but it didn't work

```
${$a."_".$b}="The best place to learn programming";
echo $stack_overflow;
```

Comment: It worked fine for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XBlOHB

Comment: Your updated code works!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $a = "stack";
    $b = "overflow";
    $name = $a . "_" . $b;

    $$name = "The best place to learn programming";
    echo $stack_overflow;

?>
```

Output:

```
The best place to learn programming
```

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

**EDIT:**

Your updated code:

```
${$a."_".$b}="The best place to learn programming";
echo $stack_overflow;
```

works too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my code works and even @Rizier123 code does as well(in this simplifed example)

I did a mistake in naming my variables so it would have never worked in my application

Comment: I would recommend you to edit your question(http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27531913/edit) and write this!(mark it as an edit if you do) Otherwise some people may down vote this.(from my experience)